# Going back to the default QGIS styles

Tags: qgis, style

I applied a style to QGIS using the qt_material package and set a new Window icon and title:

```
from qt_material import apply_stylesheet
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication.instance()        
apply_stylesheet(app, theme='light_cyan_500.xml', invert_secondary=True)
icon = QIcon("new icon path")
self.iface.mainWindow().setWindowIcon(icon)
self.iface.mainWindow().setWindowTitle("new title")
```

Using the following line of code I can go back to the default style but some things like the default texts do not change. How can I reverse all the changes and go back to the default styles and window icon and title?

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
app.setStyleSheet(QgsApplication.defaultStylePath())  # or app.setStyleSheet("")
```

[image]